# Cassandra Non-Counter Family

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I'm attempted to execute the following CQL 3 statement

```
 CREATE TABLE summary (
                id uuid,
                "client" bigint, 
                "campaign" text, 
                "unit" bigint,
                "view" counter,
                PRIMARY KEY ("client", "campaign", "unit"));
```

The error I'm getting is that I cannot create a counter column on a non-counter column family.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

The solution to this issue is that any non-counter column must be part of the primary key. The column id uuid was the one causing the issue, removing it allowed the table to be created.

Answer (score 6):

Tables that contain counters can only contain counters.

Comment: So it can have only counters and a single key?

Comment: multiple primary keys are accepted: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation of the current counter implementation.  You can't mix counters and regular columns in the same table.  So you need a separate table for counters.

They are thinking of removing this limitation in Cassandra 3.x.  See this [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9810).

(migrated from [Cassandra non counter family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562500/cassandra-non-counter-family))