# Cassandra non counter family

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I attempted to create a table with counter as one of the column type in cassandra but getting the following error:

> ConfigurationException: ErrorMessage code=2300 [Query invalid because
>   of configuration issue] message="Cannot add a counter column
>   (transaction_count) in a non counter column family"

My table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MARKET_DATA_TRANSACTION_COUNT (
TRADE_DATE TIMESTAMP,      
SECURITY_EXCHANGE TEXT,
PRODUCT_CODE TEXT,
SYMBOL TEXT,
SPREAD_TYPE TEXT,     
USER_DEFINED TEXT,
PRODUCT_GUID TEXT,
CHANNEL_ID INT,  
SECURITY_TYPE TEXT,
INSTRUMENT_GUID TEXT,
SECURITY_ID INT,   
TRANSACTION_COUNT COUNTER,
PRIMARY KEY (TRADE_DATE));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra Non-Counter Family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596618/cassandra-non-counter-family)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a limitation of the current counter implementation.  You can't mix counters and regular columns in the same table.  So you need a separate table for counters.

They are thinking of removing this limitation in Cassandra 3.x.  See this [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9810).

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly the answer to the question, might help some people with the similar error.

If you can make other columns as PRIMARY KEY then its possible.

```
Eg: CREATE TABLE rate_data (ts varchar, type varchar, rate counter, PRIMARY KEY (ts, type));
```

Comment: the question has a different primary key which is not a counter , yet the error